# Spring Roo: This relationship is managed from the side

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-roo

I am currently experiencing an issue in an app I am developing using Spring Roo 1.2.5. The front end hives me the message "This relationship is managed from the Hierarchy side".

My code in Hierarchy.java is as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
private za.co.itdynamics.survey.domain.Hierarchy parentHierarchy;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parentHierarchy")
private Set<za.co.itdynamics.survey.domain.Hierarchy> childHierarchies = new HashSet<za.co.itdynamics.survey.domain.Hierarchy>();
```

So basically a Hierarchy can have one parent Hierarchy and multiple child hierarchies. I generated this code with the Roo commands:

```
field reference --fieldName parentHierarchy --type ~.domain.Hierarchy
field set --fieldName childHierarchies --type ~.domain.Hierarchy --cardinality ONE_TO_MANY --mappedBy parentHierarchy --class ~.domain.Hierarchy
```

If anyone can assist I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard roo web-scaffold has no support for manage one-to-many relation in the "one" side.

If you need do it this way you must modify the create and update page by hand:

1. modify the create.jspx and update.jspx to generate the required html to manage the "children" list
2. modify the *Controler.java to push-in the "update" and "create" methods to handle the "children" list.

Also, you can look at [gvNIX](https://code.google.com/p/gvnix/) which includes support to generate master-details views using shell commands.